# Nginx + React fail to load resources

Tags: reactjs, nginx

[image: nginx conf]

Hey. I have a problem with react. I use '/' path for client (some static html content), and '/panel' for example for another server using 1 domain.
But i have errors which don't load my react page.

So on home location (http://localhost/) all good.
http://localhost/panel - only 'react app' in title.

[image: browser errors]

Comment: Please provide your nginx conf as a text.

Comment: I think further detail is needed. Can you show the directory structure in the server? Particularly the `/home/coder/staticHtml`? Could you also post the nginx.conf in text inside the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your React app tries to load the CSS and JS from the root path. Configure [the homePage field in package json](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) to be

```
"homePage": "/panel"
```

Comment: Do provide your `nginx.conf` and error messages as text, not images anyways, please. It is way more accessible (and the error screenshot is barely readable)